# Can't view my site within my network, but others can

Tags: wordpress, web-deployment, web-hosting

I'm unable to view my WordPress site hosted on hobohost.com, it doesn't work on my computer or my phone in any browser. However, if I hop off my wi-fi and use cellular it works!

This occurred a few times yesterday but eventually came back, I think it's related to when I try to upload new files (via FTP) to my site. I did it successfully once yesterday.

This AM when I checked the site it was working, as soon as I tried to connect to the server via FTP it stopped working for me.

I used ipconfig /flushdns to flush the DNS, and I reset my WiFi to no avail! Please help this noob deploy his first site!

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
http://simplesmallbusinesssites.com is the site. When I try to visit the site it will load for a while and then display a message:
"This site can't be reached"
and tells me to try checking the connection.

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information is available in the [help]. Please delete your question here before asking on that other site. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's tools to check the status of your HTTP requests. My guess is that you will sell terrible TTFBs (time to first byte) greater than a few seconds. On my site hosted by a very well known hosting provider the TTFBs are about 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Hey guys sorry if this is the wrong site. I thought deploying a site and using FTP would be programming related. Should I still delete this question? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got the answer to my question,

I created a ticket on my hosting site and this is what they said.

Your IP address was blocked for multiple invalid FTP login attempts.

I guess while trying to edit my site I had failed login too many times and was blocked, good to know. Thanks for all the help.